# $location.search() returns empty object when reloading a page

Tags: angularjs, url

I am using AngularJs to build a web app.I have a search page.Everytime the user tape a query I get the data from the backend and I update the url using **$location.search()** service.When the user hit the refresh button I want to save the state of the view (the same query).I use $location.search() to get the current query but it returns an empty object and the controller is reloaded so even the scope is gone(the scope containing the user query).I am using ng-route and I configure the reloadOnsearch=false.How can handle the url change and the refresh button using $location.search() service ?

```
 app.controller('resultCrtl',function($scope,myService,$http,$location,$window) {
 /*guetting query from previous view*/
$scope.userquery=myService.get();

   var uri;
/*testing the refresh */
  if(!myService.get())
 {
 var loc=$location.search('query');
  $window.alert(loc);
    /* it returns an empty object*/
  }
else {

    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : '/response/' + $scope.userquery
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.result = data;
        uri=encodeURI($scope.userquery);
        $location.search('query',uri);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert( "failure");
    });
 $scope.search=function(){
  /* same code to get data and update the url */
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it will be blank after refresh.
'$location.search('query',uri);' will change or update the address bar of browser only. So after refresh you can get this value from browser address bar using $stateParams.query and use it further wherever you want to... :)
Hope it will help you out. :)

Comment: actually I am working with ngroute I guess $stateParams is provided with ui-router module.The problem here when the page is refreshed the query is empty so I can't get anything at all...Thanks anyway :)